# How was the Stack Exchange OpenID login menu created?

Tags: support, user-interface

The Stack Exchange OpenID login page is the best I have ever seen. Is it something the team rolled itself? And if so, were any open source libraries used in its creation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is based on

http://code.google.com/p/openid-selector/

With some relatively trivial modifications.